# Can I get underneath a BGA mounted chip?

Tags: bga

I want to get to some pin signals on a mounted MCU, but it's a ball mounted / soldered one ...

Is there way to 'hack' underneath it to get some signals out? Any usual home-lab setup people came up with ?

Comment: I would say it's almost impossible. Just removing it and resoldering it back on successfully is enough of a challenge.

Comment: Do you know if there are some special sockets for BGA's so that, you can un-solder the chip, connect that socket to the board, then drop the chip into the socket. .?  Something like that ..

Comment: This is a super ascended master Jedi ... level trick. Why do you want to do it? Is it impossible to achieve fully or in part by inference from available signals elsewhere? || Importantly, why do you want to connect AT the BGA device itself? - do the relevant PCB traces go somewhere else or are the pins unterminated?

Comment: @v01d  W2635A sit down and put down the coffee before you check the price.  maybe you could design something like that using a stack of pcb for the column

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Because wanna get inside inside the MCU, may be connect emulator/debugger, and spy on it's code. Also dump internal flash contents. Wrt to available signals, haven't found yet on the board the routed out signals i want ...  Also, is there a "home-made" X-Ray for PCB ??   Or 'cheap' one :P   I want to look inside the layers.

Comment: @Jasen ok, about to put my glasses on & sip some, while googling for W2635A..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps fron below with very thin drill bit and lots of care.

it's peobably easier to remove the chip using hot air, and then glue and solder the probe wires in (eg: use #40 enammeled magnet wire) then re-ball and re-solder the BGA. I find that 800 grit sandpaper works well to strip fine magnet wire.

Comment: hey thanks for answering, I will now try parse every point you have given here and do some googling.

Comment: can you recommend a hot air (gun?) good for removing MCU chips like this?  one that also can set temp accurate enough not to damage the chip.

Comment: @Jasen You're not implying to solder it back to the PCB with a magnet wire sticking out from under the BGA, are you? Because the planarity of the BGA gets ruined easily enough by a bad reballing or even just bad plating on the PCB, let alone wire and glue being underneath the BGA.

Comment: yeah I am, use thin wire. and use the glue  outside of the bga perimeter

Comment: a custom adaptor made from 2 sided flex pcb could be another option but that's likely to be no easier to apply than a few wires. and hard to get flat,  something like W2635A is not an option for most home labs.

Comment: @Jasen  ok, found W2635A , and, the typical price made my sip of tea go wrong throat ... So yea, not my home lab $.      BTW, I'm accepting your answer, because I got your advice & useful info, as well as all the other's comments which I highly appreciated.